# Javascript not showing for Slick Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have installed the jquery-slick-rails gem with following git : https://github.com/bodrovis/jquery-slick-rails

Now I have the folowing files

**assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.slick
```

**assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
/*
 *= require headerandfooter
 *= require_self
 *= require slick
 */

+bits of CSS here ...
```

**But I can't see any Javascript for this gem on my page.** Only JS on my page is :

```
 <script src="/javascripts/default.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>
```

for information here is my **views/layouts/application.html.erb** I haven't modifie yet (not advised on github page):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'headerandfooter', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    params[:controller], media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'default', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
  </script>
  <![endif]-->

  </head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is inside of your `assets/javascripts/default.js` file?

Comment: It is a big file. There is some styling. The header contains only this: <h1>Routing Error</h1>. Then a div id='traces'. Then lots of HTML with the word 'routes' repeating a lot. Then at the end some javascript with the words 'console' 'REPLconsole' repeating.. But overall nothing like the SLICK js..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added your jQuery plugin related js file to your `application.js` file, but you haven't included it in your `layouts/application.html.erb` file (only `default.js`)

So, you either need to include `application.js` file in your layout or include `jquery.slick.js` file in `default.js` or your layout.

Comment: Many thanks. It works ! Actually what is funny is that I have added the slick stylesheet only in the Application.css (*= require slick) and it shows in the HTML. So I was not sure if the application.html.erb was really important to be changed.