# Javascript doesn't work unless I include it directly in the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to utilize a few jquery plugins in my ruby on rails project. However, none of them work unless I import them via a cdn or put the code directly into the view. I'm not sure why this is occurring.

This is my application.js

```html
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.bootstrap-autohidingnavbar.js
//= require jquery.scrolline.js
```

I tried using just 'require_tree ." but that didn't work. So, I tried to include specifically the plugins that I needed. That still didn't work. The only thing that works is when the code is written directly in my view file, and then I call it.

Comment: Which one exactly didn't work?

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work ? You have an error ?  You can't see js in your view ? Is your layout include a javascript tag to application.js ?

Comment: Bootstrap has dependency over jquery, so include jquery first and then the rest of the things. Same goes with the little plugins you have mentioned.

Comment: By not working, I mean that when I call the javascript and try to utilize its functionality, it just doesn't work. Nothing changes. But as soon as I include the code in the view it works just fine

Comment: Do you see any errors in your javascript console?

Comment: I'm getting uncaught referenceError: jquery is not defined. Weird. I have jquery on the page as a CDN...

Comment: You have to write  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> to head of your html.

Comment: Have you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/37443674/957185 (you have to amend the application.html.erb)

Answer (score 1):

So I guess what the issue is, you have added jquery to your `applicatoin.html.erb` from cdn. And You have done it after you have done your `javascript_include_tag` which includes the manifest file.

You have to include javascript first and then your application.js file. And if you if you're doing it via cdn, you can get rid of `//= require jquery` from your application.js file.

Let me know if it solves the issue.